# Rails 4 : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity but data still insert into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, authenticity

I apply the **CSRF** in Controller by adding this:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     protect_from_forgery
  end
```

and I do a post request to my API using **Postman**.
The funny result is I can't verify **CSRF**, but the data I send still be inserted into DB.

Here is the server log.

```
 Processing by Api::ListingsController
   Parameters: {"listing"=>{...}}
 Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "listings" ...
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 Completed 201 Created in 54ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)
```

Seems everything is fine, and data is in DB now!
Why is **CSRF** not working?

Anyone can give any explains?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 behaviours that a csrf token mismatch can trigger:

- raise an exception (`:exception`)
- reset the session to a new, empty session (`:reset_session`)
- use an empty session for the request, but don't reset it completely (`:null_session`)

The rationale for the last 2 is that the point of a CSRF attack is usually to abuse the fact that the user is already logged in and thus the browser will send session cookies with the request. Therefore reseting or ignoring the session (assuming that is where credentials are stored) will make the request proceed as an unauthenticated request.

If the application doesn't require the user to be logged in then `:null_session` and `:reset_session` will allow the request to proceed.

The default behaviour has changed over the years, but as of rails 4.2 is is `:null_session`. You can change it by specifying a `with` option to `protect_from_forgery`

Comment: Thx man!
I added 'protect_from_forgery with: :null_session' in 'ApplicationController', but the problem is still there. 
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity but data still insert into database.

Comment: That's what I was explaining - null session just clears out the session. If you want an exception to be raised, use :exception

Answer (score 0):

In `ApplicationController` you can add

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format      == 'application/json' }
    # Or
    # skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```

Comment: None of this works in my case.
I have am app based on Michael Hartl user authorization.
It is based on Rails 4.2.5 and worked until morning when I executed a bundle update. After that no log in, log out, etc. Sessions are not created. Previous bundle update executed was 2 days ago. App worked at that time. I have an API build on top of this app which is working. Only the main app died. Can't make it work again. The main app is sending the wrong token for verification instead the correct one stored in the users table. Don't know what generated this wrong token.